# Model flow network

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-theory

There are n people, some of them hold key. There are ⌈n/5⌉ doors, to open each door, at least two of those people who have key have to be at the door. A max of 5 people can go to one door, each people can only go to one of the doors that they can reach, each people have to go to a door so no one is left behind. All doors are required to be opened, but there may not have enough people holding key. How can I model this problem into a flow network in order to find the allocation (any combination that satisfies the constraint) of people to open all the doors?

I have a model like this below. There are people nodes and door nodes. Intermidiate nodes are added.

The edges connecting source to each people node have capacity of 1.

The edges connecting people nodes and door nodes have capacity of 1, each people is connected to 1 or more doors (the doors they can reach). If a people have key, he's connected to an intermidiate node which then connects to the door node with lower bound of 2 (2 people with key needed to open the door) and capacity of 5.

The edges connecting door nodes and sink have capacity of 5since a max of 5 people can go to one door.

- Now the problem is how to modify this model for it to work with standard Ford Fulkerson

[image]

Comment: Here's an idea: If you associate a flow of n with each person having no key and n+1 with each person having a key, then an edge with capacity 5n+2 simulates a door in the respect that it limits the number of people at the door to 5 and requires 2 keys for saturation. The full answer requires more tricks, but maybe this will get you started. The gist is to encode "person" and "key" in the single scalar quantity "flow" using a lexicographic representation.

Comment: Do you mean setting the capacity of the edges from people to door to n(or n+1 if there is a key)? and the capacity from door to sink would be 5n+2?

Comment: You'll need a different network.

Comment: "some of them hold key"  Please clarify.  If every door must be opened ( as suggested in comment by you ) then these needs to be at least `ciel(n/2.5)` keyholders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Model**

"*no one is left behind*"  That is a difficult optimization function, since it has only two values ( 0 or 1 ).  To get started, I suggest using "maximize number of people that get through the doors".

"*The edges connecting door nodes and sink have capacity of 5 and lower bound of 2*"  We need to account for the possibility that some doors may not be reachable by 5 people, and that some doors may not be required.  I suggest that the capacity of these links be set to the minimum of 5 and the number of people who can reach the door, and no minimum.

"*There are people nodes*"  In this problem, all people are not equal.  Some have keys and some do not.  So you need two kinds of people nodes.

**2-stage Greedy Algorithm**

*Stage 1*

- Order doors into decreasing value.  ( Door value is minimum of number of people who can reach the door and 5 )
- Assign people with keys, two by two, to the doors in order of decreasing value

*Stage 2*

- Construct flow model:

  - people without keys
  - people with keys but not assigned in stage 1
  - doors that were opened in stage 1
  - Link source and people with capacity 1
  - Link people and open doors they can reach with capacity 1
  - Link open open doors and sink with capacity 3
- Apply standard maximum flow algorithm ( i.e. Ford Fulkerson )

**Example**

A randomly generated example

```
15 People, 3 Doors
Keyholders: person0 person2 person3 person4 person5 person6 person8 person10 person11 person12 person13 person14
Door door0 reachable by person0 person1 person3 person7 person9 person10 person13 person14
Door door1 reachable by person2 person3 person4 person6 person7 person8 person9 person11 person12 person13 person14
Door door2 reachable by person2 person3 person5 person10 person11 person13
```

The algorithm gives

```
Keyholder person0 assigned to door 2
Keyholder person2 assigned to door 2
Door 2 opened
Keyholder person3 assigned to door 0
Keyholder person4 assigned to door 0
Door 0 opened
Keyholder person5 assigned to door 1
Keyholder person6 assigned to door 1
Door 1 opened
Total People who got through 14 of 15
person0 through door2
person2 through door2
person3 through door0
person4 through door0
person5 through door1
person6 through door1
person1 through door0
person7 through door0
person9 through door1
person10 through door2
person11 through door2
person12 through door1
person13 through door2
person14 through door1
```

**C++ implementation**

The C++ code for setting up the example and running the algoorithm is at https://gist.github.com/JamesBremner/f9750d7e5dd646e007b9344d9d9ec5b7

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explaination, I'll have a closer look soon as possible. To clarify, all doors are needed, if a door cannot be opened, there is not a feasible solution, we can have that.

Comment: Please edit your question to with this change, so that everyone can see it.  Do not bury important clarifications in comments.

Comment: This simplifies the question! Now it can be solved in two simple steps.  1: Assign two keyholders to each door.  If that cannot be done, stop.  2. Remove assigned keyholders and solve the remaining problem with the door to sink links all set to capacity 3.

Comment: I have updated the code ( https://gist.github.com/JamesBremner/f9750d7e5dd646e007b9344d9d9ec5b7 ) to optionally specify that all doors MUST be opened.

Comment: Thank you, I've added the clarification. Also, I updated my model, where intermidiate nodes between people with key and doors are added.

Comment: I'm trying to model the problem so that it can be solved with a single Ford Fulkerson.

Comment: Ford Fulkerson algorithm is the standard method to solve a maximum flow problem.  A single call to my implementation of that algorithm is what is used in my answer and the code in the application I have provided to solve your problem.  I do not think there is anything more you need to try.

Comment: FYI I have updated the code to use  Edmonds–Karp algorithm which is better defined than Ford Fulkerson .  Details  https://github.com/JamesBremner/PathFinder/blob/d29842d85cec600a75eb61763edf221ba51d531f/src/GraphTheory.cpp#L778-L788